# Как сделать цвет окон WPF-приложения, таким же как цвет Windows10

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, color

Хотелось бы чтобы цвет приложения зависел от цвета выбранного в Windows10.

Есть такой код:

```
<Window x:Class="ToDo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ToDo"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="438" Width="435" Background="#FF129E98">
<Grid Margin="0,0,12,0">
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53" Height="35" Click="button_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53" Height="35" Click="button1_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53" Height="35" Click="button2_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="387" Width="347"/>
</Grid>
```

Еще нашел такую строчку, но не знаю куда её писать:

```
"{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}"
```

Пробовал так:

```
    <Window.Background>
    <"{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}">
</Window.Background>
```

Но это неправильно. Помогите пожалуйста, впервые создаю WPF-приложение.

UPD
Использовал это:

```
    <Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}"/>
</Window.Background>
```

Хотелось бы чтобы приложение полностью стало зеленым.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так пишите `Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}"` внутри тега Window

Comment: @АндрейNOP `Title="MainWindow" Height="438" Width="435" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}">` и выдает ошибку "#FFFFFFFF" не является допустимым значением для свойства "Background".

Comment: Действительно, странно, что конвертация в кисть не срабатывает автоматически. Попробуйте так: https://pastebin.com/C02jWD5e

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не получается, окно приложения цвет не поменяло. К вопросу скрин приложил

Comment: Ну дык это другой цвет, причем вы можете взять не цвет, а сразу кисть: `Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}"` Все константы можно найти здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.systemcolors(v=vs.110).aspx